# Query using JOIN instead of INTERSECT

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a schema like this:

```
// table badge_types
id | name
+++|++++++++++
1  | mentor
2  | proctor
3  | doctor

// table badges
id | badge_type_id | user_id     
+++|+++++++++++++++|++++++++
1  | 1             | 5
2  | 1             | 6
3  | 2             | 6
4  | 3             | 6
5  | 2             | 19
6  | 3             | 20
```

What I want to do, is select all `badge_types` that a particular user has not yet gotten. In the above example, calling the query for:

`user_id = 5` returns `badge_type_id` `2` and `3`

`user_id = 6` returns `empty` set (user got all of them already)

`user_id = 19` returns `badge_type_id` `1` and `3`

I can do this with an `INTERSECT` clause. But I'm wondering if it can be done with a simple `JOIN`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For what database?  Far as I know INTERSECT is only supported on SQL Server and Oracle...

Comment: MySQL. I see now that it doesn't support INTERSECT. Good thing you answered!

Comment: @OMGPonies Postgres and SQLite (most prolly many more) support it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:

```
   SELECT bt.name
     FROM BADGE_TYPES bt
LEFT JOIN BAGDES b ON b.badge_type_id = bt.id
                  AND b.user_id = ?
    WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

### Using NOT EXISTS

```
   SELECT bt.name
     FROM BADGE_TYPES bt
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                       FROM BADGES b 
                      WHERE b.badge_type_id = bt.id
                        AND b.user_id = ?)
```

### Using NOT IN

```
   SELECT bt.name
     FROM BADGE_TYPES bt
    WHERE bt.id NOT IN (SELECT b.badge_type_id
                       FROM BADGES b 
                      WHERE b.user_id = ?)
```

### MySQL

If the columns are [not nullable, LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is the best choice](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).  If they [are nullable, `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` are the best choice](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

### SQL Server

Mind that [on SQL Server, `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` perform better than LEFT JOIN /IS NULL if the columns in question are not nullable](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).

### Oracle

For [Oracle, all three are equivalent but LEFT JOIN/IS NULL and NOT EXISTS are preferable if columns aren't nullable](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The first answer is facepalm for me, can't believe I didn't put the AND b.user_id in before. 

Do you know of any sites that give increasingly harder SQL practice queries? I want to learn it well, but it won't happen with my minimal exposure to it.

Comment: @Jasie: Google TSQL challenges, but they're SQL Server functionality oriented, which MySQL might not provide.  Or hang out on SO, reviewing questions from the past few days...